# aiohttp not able to get all cookies from session

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, aiohttp

When using AIOHTTP to cookies of a session, it doesnt show the complete cookies.

I have tried to index through cookies, but it still just shows very few of them. I believe its using something called simple cookie but i could be wrong.

```py
async with s.get(endpoint) as add:
    print (endpoint.url)
    sitetext = (await endpoint.text())
    cookies = s.cookie_jar.filter_cookies(endpoint)

    for each in cookies.items():
        print (each)
```

Which yields results like:

```
('__cfduid', <Morsel: __cfduid=d2719c3095fb81ad69c19507dbe8bd7a01566353842>)
('_orig_referrer', <Morsel: _orig_referrer=>)
('_landing_page', <Morsel: _landing_page=productname>)
```

But this isn't the full cookies of the session, when i go and view the headers there are more cookies too, but im unsure of how to extract cookies from headers.

I tried getting cookies through headers by doing:

```py
async with s.get(endpoint) as add:
    print (endpoint.url)
    sitetext = (await endpoint.text())
    cookies = s.cookie_jar.filter_cookies(endpoint)

    print (endpoint.headers['Set-Cookie'])
```

But this only gives me the first Set-Cookie and not the rest.

Edit: Im using AIOHTTP as this program has to be async and non blocking. (i know requests is much easier)

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not sure, but I had similar problem. Try this:

```
cookies = response.cookies
cookie_string = "; ".join([str(value) for _, value in cookies.items()]).replace('Set-Cookie: ', '')
```

I have such format of answer:

`__Host-ariregweb=g4q8icpEmmIdHnQmFSNsfHdNhLLsgISKE7XRzphrLiscb4pSIzrpRLm9aiLCHqXa; Domain=ariregister.rik.ee; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=lax; Secure; __cf_bm=GIYOJNShc1kY79bPk7GG1U6T.jV6K4BG8DLQoc70NT8-1671428340-0-AcxNKFuuhvkmblvy/q4WPGEPezvLQUL8/k6NeylOmaX5awlf1L7eOWnc55DGMsyPzpv5YKUDL6w100KlzzjsJVE=; Domain=ariregister.rik.ee; expires=Mon, 19-Dec-22 06:09:00 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure; _cfuvid=0EIfdSb4ltpOgYzKuMthWVvN0x5L3kn_uCfhyvBEk34-1671428340155-0-604800000; Domain=ariregister.rik.ee; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure`

As I see you try to bypass the CloudFlare protection. CloudFlare detects your scripted requests and gives `403 Forbidden` status. So that you get non-completed `cookies`.

I recommend you to use `Insomnia` and `Fiddler` to understand what is happening with your request in browser and script. The only way to bypass the protection system is to define the key moments in headers or the character of request.

By the way, I have this problem currently. If you send the request through `Fiddler` in `Python`, you might be able to recieve completed `cookies`.

Good luck. But let me know if the solution was useful for your case.